# Displaying contents corresponding to the word entered in a text box in ipad app

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad

I have plans to create an app which gives me the list of words and sentences associated with the text which i entered in my text field.Ok let me elaborate.I have a dictionary in my project consisting of words and probabily some sentences and then i have a text box.Whenever i enter some word in that text box say i enter "Rose" ,then words corresponding to the word like "Rose","Roses","Rose is beautiful" etc (these words and sentences will be in dictionary)must be shown onto the list and when any of the word or sentence is selected then that must be displayed on the text box,Just like the case of google search engine ,where we type a word and we get the list of words and sentences containing that word.

So anyone having anyidea about this,please give me thedirection from where to start.

Thanks,
Christy

Comment: Can anyone give me a better answer please with any demo code if possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When u finished typing the word in the text field, search your dictionary to see if the word is present. If the word is present add the results to an array or something and use it to display it on a table view. When the user clicks on it then you can use the info to display on a text view.

Comment: I dont have any demo code right now. You can make use of `NSPredicate` to search for items and then get the results in an array. Use the array to populate the tableview.

Comment: how to cretate sqlite db in simulator,do u know that